# How does a liquefied gas work as a coolant?

Tags: cryogenics

What makes liquefied Helium a better coolant than other liquefied gases (like Nitrogen, for example)? Is it because it has a lower boiling point (in which case, will it cool any substance it's in contact with till it reaches that point?) 
A clear explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "better coolant"? LHe reaches lower temperatures than LN2. But LN2 has a higher thermal capacity and can therefore extract more heat.

Comment: By a "better coolant" I mean that it can reach lower temperatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

The boiling temperature of helium is lower than of any other gas, and you can use it to cool other substances to that temperature.

If you drop a small item into a bucket of cold water, the item will cool to the temperature of the water. At the same time the water temperature will rise a little as it absorbs the heat of the object dropped into it. If the water is at boiling temperature, its temperature cannot rise until it has evaporated completely. Hence water at 100C can cool things to 100C, without any rise of its temperature.

The same happens when you put things into liquid helium: things cool to that temperature, and some of the helium boils away to remove the heat, so its temperature remains constant.